# Sum or aggregate minute dataset to daily dataset, applying different function to different columns for every 60 rows in R

Tags: r

I have this dataset

```
x<-data.frame(matrix(c("01-01-2010", "01-01-2010", "01-01-2010","01-01-2010"," 00:01"," 00:02"," 00:03"," 00:04", "12.2", "12.1", "13.1", "11.4", "12", "13", "5", "8","12", "4","7","9", "16.9", "17.5","18.8", "21.0"), ncol=6))
names(x)<-c("date","time","pressure","temperature","rain","windspeed")

        date     time pressure  temperature rain windspeed
1 01-01-2010   00:01     12.2          12   12      16.9
2 01-01-2010   00:02     12.1          13    4      17.5
3 01-01-2010   00:03     13.1           5    7      18.8
4 01-01-2010   00:04     11.4           8    9      21.0
```

This is a simplified version of my dataset.
My dataset starts from 01-01-2010  00:01 to 12-31-2017 23:59 .

I'm looking to

1) average pressure, temperature and windspeed into becoming hourly data.

2) sum up rain into becoming hourly data.

Making a new hourly timestamp to paste all these new data is simple, I just need to know what is the best way to average and sum different columns, and up to only 60 rows repeatedly (60 minutes to make 1 hour) until 12-31-2017 23:59

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the use of tidy packages and tibbletime to do the task clearly and easily. I've added a bit of cleanup code to get your sample data in the format needed.

This method is highly repeatable and interpretable. TibbleTime allows you to do lots of aggregations and rolling calculations on time based data while using common functions.

```
# The provided example data -----------------------------------------------
x<-data.frame(matrix(c("01-01-2010", "01-01-2010", "01-01-2010","01-01-2010"," 00:01"," 00:02"," 00:03"," 00:04", "12.2", "12.1", "13.1", "11.4", "12", "13", "5", "8","12", "4","7","9", "16.9", "17.5","18.8", "21.0"), ncol=6),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(x)<-c("date","time","pressure","temperature","rain","windspeed")

# Load Libraries ----------------------------------------------------------
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibbletime)

# Fix column classes of data ----------------------------------------------
x <- x %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(pressure:windspeed),as.numeric)

# Convert to tibbletime object --------------------------------------------
x <- x %>%
  mutate(date_time = mdy_hm(paste0(date,time))) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = date_time) %>%
  select(date_time,everything())

# Use tibbletime function to roll up hourly -------------------------------
x_hourly <- x %>%
  collapse_by('hourly',side = 'start') %>%
  group_by(date_time) %>%
  summarise(pressure = mean(pressure, na.rm = TRUE),
            temperature = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
            rain = sum(rain, na.rm = TRUE),
            windspeed = mean(windspeed, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Results:

```
> x_hourly
# A time tibble: 1 x 5
# Index: date_time
  date_time           pressure temperature  rain windspeed
  <dttm>                 <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2010-01-01 00:01:00     12.2         9.5    32      18.6
```

Comment: Hi, When i try it on my dataset, apparently it's not working. I get an error at "convert to tibbletime object" Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

I guess it's because my time class is character?  I check the new date_time, it's all NA

Comment: This usually means something is missing or in a different format. I assumed that your date was in the format mdy_hm. Is the date possibly in dmy_hm format?

Comment: Hi, the date and time are divided into two separate columns, as shown in the example df. The time format is hh:mm, I think that's where the problem occurs

Comment: Checking the class of the time, it says character

Comment: The example data you gave ran fine on my side. I assume you're having a problem with the full data set? It should be fine if data is in hh:mm format. But it would crash if the date was in dd-mm-yyyy format instead of mm-dd-yyyy format. It might also crash if some of the rows were missing data.

Comment: mdy_hm and ymd_hm both take character inputs.

Comment: Oh! Also, your sample data had a space in the hh:mm. " 00:01". You might have to change the following line `mutate(date_time = mdy_hm(paste0(date,time))) %>%` to `mutate(date_time = mdy_hm(paste(date,time))) %>%` if some of those don't have a space.

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry for the late reply. I tweaked around a little bit, and it worked ! Thx for your suggestion. However, the tibbletime thing kinda change the data into some kind of messy combination of red font, semi-transparent font ....... is there anyway I can turn it back to normal?

Comment: Hi i managed to turn it back to common data frame by, well, data-framing it as a new data frame lol... anyway thx for all the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
# sample data
x1 <- data.frame(matrix(c("01-01-2010", "01-01-2010", "01-01-2010","01-01- 
  2010","00:00:01","00:00:02","00:00:03","00:00:04", "12.2", "12.1", "13.1", "11.4", 
  "12", "13", "5", "8","12", "4","7","9", "16.9", "17.5","18.8", "21.0"), ncol=6))
x2 <- data.frame(matrix(c("01-01-2010", "01-01-2010", "01-01-2010","01-01- 
  2010","01:00:01","01:00:02","01:00:03","01:00:04", "12.2", "12.1", "13.1", "11.4", 
  "12", "13", "5", "8","12", "4","7","9", "16.9", "17.5","18.8", "21.0"), ncol=6))
x <- rbind(x1, x2)
names(x) <- c("date","time","pressure","temperature","rain","windspeed")
x[,3:6] <- apply(x[,3:6], 2, as.numeric)

# two separate aggregates 
aggregate(x[,c('pressure', 'temperature', 'windspeed')], by = list(paste0(x$date, 
  substring(x$time, 1, 2))), FUN = 'mean')
aggregate(x[,c('rain'), drop = FALSE], 
  by = list(paste0(x$date, substring(x$time, 1, 2))), FUN = 'sum')

#       Group.1 pressure temperature windspeed
#1 01-01-201000     12.2         9.5     18.55
#2 01-01-201001     12.2         9.5     18.55

#       Group.1 rain
#1 01-01-201000   32
#2 01-01-201001   32
```

Comment: hi, it's not summing up nor does it averaging properly

Comment: Hi, do you mean in the sample data? Which sum/average is wrong? E.g. rain sum, 12+4+7+9 = 32

Comment: Hmm it's not coming out in my console. I'll try again and let u know